# Join two variable and LCD print

Tags: c++, c, date, lcd

I am having a variable name day=3 . I wanted to print on lCD as 03 .concept i am trying to impliment is 
 as below

```
int term1;
int term2;
int day=3;
term1=day%10;// here i get the actual term day
term2=(int)(day/10). here i get term 0.
```

Now i wanted to print on lcd by joining term1 and term2.

```
lcd.print(concat(term1&term2)
```

question here is how to join term1 and term 2 to get result displayed as 03 instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
lcd.print(term1);
lcd.print(term2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store values of day

```
char day_string[3];
int day;
if (day < 10)
{   
    // prepend a 0 to day if day is one digit
    day_string[0]='0';
    day_string[1]=day;
    day_string[2]='\0';
    lcd.print(day_string);
}
else
    // if day is a two digit value print itself 
    lcd.print(day);
```